# Should I avoid using '../' in HTML?

Tags: html, web, path

`../` can be used in HTML hyperlinks to go to the folder one level up. Is it supported by the oldest and depreceated browsers/standards? Should it be used casually? Should I avoid using it, just like `goto`?

Comment: The `<p>` tag for example is also supported by the oldest and "depreceated"  browers - that's no reason not to use it...

Comment: It's also worth noting that `../` is not just a browser specific feature. It's pretty much a universal way to handle paths across platforms. That being said, for links it will probably make more sense using paths relative to the root directory, not the document itself. So if you are in `example.com/test/test.htm`, use `/test2/test2.htm` instead of `../test2/test2.htm`.

Answer (score 0):

`../` can be used casually without a problem and doesn't have much to do with browser compatibility. Since you're using a relative link you're just referencing the path to a document.

(Let's say you have a domain `http://example.com`) You'll also notice when using `../` in your url that when you hover over the link the url will have changed from `../folder/index` to `http://example.com/folder/index`.

One thing that's considered best practice (by some people) for relative links is using a root-relative link. So instead of `../folder/index` you would just use `/folder/index`

More information about links can be found here: http://www.iraqtimeline.com/maxdesign/basicdesign/principles/prinlinks.html